# Source Annotation in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to insert a source annotation below the x-axis label in Plotly? I can get an annotation below the x-axis, but if I change the margins, the annotation gets cut off. For now, I am able to put an annotation between the x-axis and the x-axis label. Below is a MWE for the included chart.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  layout(title = 'Sample Chart',
         margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, t = 60, b = 60),
         annotations = list(text = 'Source: U.S. Census Bureau.',
                            font = list(size = 12),
                            showarrow = FALSE,
                            xref = 'paper', x = -0.03,
                            yref = 'paper', y = -0.2))
```

[image]

I would like to move the "Source: U.S. Census Bureau" below the x-axis title.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add line breaks using html tags

```
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
+     layout(title = 'Sample Chart',xaxis=list(
+         title = 'x <br> Source: U.S. Census Bureau.'),
+            margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, t = 60, b = 60))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to keep it left-aligned though? I tried playing around with <div align="left"> and <div style="text-align:left">, but neither of those worked.

Comment: I don't see anything specific to help with the left alignment - you can get an overview of the html tags here - https://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/